# How can I capture layered windows with DirectX?

Tags: c++, directx, screen-capture

I am developing a screen capture application using DirectX, the application works on most situations, except when the screen has layered windows, which is ignored by DirectX capture.

I know using GDI I can use the `CAPTUREBLT` flag to capture these windows, but I do not know how to do it with DirectX, so my question is:

Using DirectX, how can I capture layered windows?

My code:

```
LPDIRECT3D9 d3d9;
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3ddev;
IDirect3DSurface9* dest;

void Init()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    d3d9 = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

    ww = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    wh = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

    HWND hwnd = GetDesktopWindow();
    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
    ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));
    d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_UNKNOWN;
    d3dpp.BackBufferCount = 1;
    d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = ww;
    d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = wh;
    d3dpp.MultiSampleType = D3DMULTISAMPLE_NONE;
    d3dpp.MultiSampleQuality = 0;
    d3dpp.EnableAutoDepthStencil = TRUE;
    d3dpp.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D16;
    d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = hwnd;
    d3dpp.Flags = D3DPRESENTFLAG_LOCKABLE_BACKBUFFER;
    d3dpp.FullScreen_RefreshRateInHz = D3DPRESENT_RATE_DEFAULT;
    d3dpp.PresentationInterval = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_DEFAULT;

    d3d9->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, hwnd, D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &d3dpp, &d3ddev);

    d3ddev->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(ww, wh, D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM, &dest, NULL);
}


void Screenshot()
{
    d3ddev->GetFrontBufferData(0, dest);

    D3DLOCKED_RECT rect;
    ZeroMemory(&rect, sizeof(D3DLOCKED_RECT));
    dest->LockRect(&rect, NULL, D3DLOCK_READONLY);
    uchar *bits = (uchar*)rect.pBits;
    dest->UnlockRect();

    //Use bits
}

void End()
{
    dest->Release();
    d3ddev->Release();
    d3d9->Release();

    CoUninitialize();
}
```

Comment: Why do you mean by layer window? Overlay Surfaces?

Comment: When i'm referring to layered windows I'm referring to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1194281/2014561, which works to capture the screen without ignore any window, but it's a GDI way to capture screen. I'm not sure if it's a Overlay Surface.

Answer (score 0):

I capture the screen in Direct-X using:

```
HRESULT dxReadPixels(IDirect3DDevice9* Device, void* Buffer, HDC& DC, int& Width, int& Height, D3DFORMAT Format)
{
    IDirect3DSurface9* RenderTarget = nullptr;
    IDirect3DSurface9* DestTarget = nullptr;
    HRESULT result = Device->GetRenderTarget(0, &RenderTarget);

    if (result == S_OK)
    {
        if (Width == 0 || Height == 0 || Format == D3DFMT_UNKNOWN)
        {
            D3DSURFACE_DESC descriptor = {};
            RenderTarget->GetDesc(&descriptor);
            Width = descriptor.Width;
            Height = descriptor.Height;
            Format = descriptor.Format;
        }

        if (Buffer)
        {
            RenderTarget->GetDC(&DC);
            result = Device->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(Width, Height, Format, D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM, &DestTarget, nullptr);
            result = Device->GetRenderTargetData(RenderTarget, DestTarget);

            D3DLOCKED_RECT rect;
            DestTarget->LockRect(&rect, 0, D3DLOCK_READONLY);
            memcpy(Buffer, rect.pBits, Width * Height * 4);
            DestTarget->UnlockRect();
        }
    }

    SafeRelease(RenderTarget);
    SafeRelease(DestTarget);
    return result;
}
```

Not sure of any way to make it faster or anything but it works fairly well..